# How to improve the SQL joining same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am maintaining the project which using MYSQL and PHP, and i found that the database structure is like this.

```
table user

+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Tom   |
|  2 | John  |
|  3 | Peter |
|  4 | Mary  |
+----+-------+

table data

+--------+----------+----------+
| userid |   type   | content  |
+--------+----------+----------+
|      1 | gender   | male     |
|      1 | comment  | Hello    |
|      1 | phone    | 12345678 |
|      1 | username | tom      |
|    ... | ...      | ...      |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

I need to write the SQL to get the data like this

```
+-----+------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
| id  | name | gender |  phone   | comment | username |
+-----+------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|   1 | Tom  | male   | 12345678 | Hello   | tom      |
| ... | ...  | ...    |      ... | ...     | ...      |
+-----+------+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

So the SQL will be

```
SELECT user.id as "id",user.name as "name",d1.content as 'gender', d2....... FROM user
LEFT JOIN data d1 on d1.userid = user.id and d1.type = 'gender'....
LEFT JOIN...
LEFT JOIN...
LEFT JOIN...
```

It works but i think this is too complicated and hard to maintenance.The performance also not good.Also when i add more types to the table `data`, i need to add more `join` to all queries.

If the SQL already grab the data from table `data`, is it be able to filter it and no need to join it again?

Any idea to make my SQL query simpler and faster?

Comment: `SELECT ..., MAX(CASE WHEN ... = ... THEN ... END) a, MAX(CASE...) b... FROM ... GROUP BY ...` this improves readability but rarely improves performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way to do this is with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT u.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.type = 'gender' THEN content END) AS gender,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.type = 'comment' THEN content END) AS comment,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.type = 'phone' THEN content END) AS phone,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.type = 'username' THEN content END) AS username
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

Output:

```
id  gender  comment phone       username
1   male    Hello   12345678    tom
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioWWr8M6pPLcjKejQ7wRPj/0)

Comment: How to query if I want to search `WHERE gender(d.type=gender&d.content=) 'male' ` not `u.id = 1`  in this query which using `CASE`?

Comment: @Pete the simplest way would be to use a `HAVING` clause e.g. `HAVING gender='male'`